# Avoid SQL code redundancy

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Need help on avoiding the SQL code redundancy below is the SQL statement in which column dept10 and dept20 have same code but with little bit of difference.

Can someone help on how to avoid it, since due to that statement is taking too long to run.

Need help on avoid such redundancy in the SQL code `select dname from dept where deptno = xx`.

Below is the example for such sql:

```
select column1,
       column2,
       (select dname from dept where deptno=10) dept10,
       (select dname from dept where deptno=20) dept20
from dual
where column1 = xyz;
```

#

Below is the actual query which i am trying to avoid the code redundancy:-

The column amt7 and amt8 are the columns have the same sql code

```
 SELECT  /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ rr.receipt_no, 
                           sc.bill_id             bill_id, 
                           2                      AS sNo, 
                           50                     AS pk, 
                           rr.receipt_date, 
                           a.sac_no, 
                           sc.msr_no, 
                           Decode(crtd.tax_id, '14', SUM(crtd.tax_colln_amt),0) gpen, 
                            (CASE   WHEN sc.type_of_bill = 'M' AND CRTD.tax_id = 14 AND SUM(CRTD.tax_colln_amt) > 0 THEN '350300402' 
                                    WHEN sc.type_of_bill = 'R' AND CRTD.tax_id = 14 AND SUM(CRTD.tax_colln_amt) > 0 THEN '350300304' 
                                    ELSE '350300104' 
                            END)                GL_Account_code, 
                            Nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN Substr(sc.period, 1, 4) <= '2009' THEN 
                                     (SELECT    (CASE WHEN 
                                                    (SUM( Nvl(bd.bd_r_tax_amt, 0) + Nvl( bd.bd_nr_tax_amt, 0))) = 0 THEN 0 
                                                        ELSE (SUM( Nvl(bd.bd_r_tax_amt, 0)+ Nvl( bd.bd_nr_tax_amt, 0)) ) 
                                                END ) 
                                        FROM    abm_bill_detail bd, 
                                                cv_ptax_outstanding b 
                                        WHERE bd.bd_bill_id = sc.bill_id 
                                        AND b.bill_id = bd.bd_bill_id 
                                        AND b.status = 'A' 
                                        AND Substr(b.bill_code, 1, 6) = Substr(b.bill_code, 1, 6) 
                                        AND bd.bd_taxhead_id = 7 
                                        AND bd.isdeleted = 'N') 
                                    ELSE (CASE WHEN 
                                             (SELECT SUM(bdd.tax_amount) 
                                                FROM   cv_bill_detail bdd 
                                                WHERE  bdd.bill_mas_id = sc.bill_id 
                                                AND bdd.tax_id = 7 
                                                AND bdd.status = 'A') = 0 THEN 1 
                                            END ) 
                            END), 0)       amt7, 
                            Nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN Substr(sc.period, 1, 4) <= '2009' THEN 
                                     (SELECT (CASE WHEN 
                                                    (SUM( Nvl(bd.bd_r_tax_amt, 0) + Nvl( bd.bd_nr_tax_amt, 0)) ) = 0 THEN 0 
                                                        ELSE ( SUM( Nvl(bd.bd_r_tax_amt, 0) + Nvl( bd.bd_nr_tax_amt, 0))) 
                                                END ) 
                                        FROM    abm_bill_detail bd, 
                                                cv_ptax_outstanding b 
                                        WHERE bd.bd_bill_id = sc.bill_id 
                                        AND  b.bill_id = bd.bd_bill_id 
                                        AND b.status = 'A' 
                                        AND Substr(b.bill_code, 1, 6) = Substr(b.bill_code, 1, 6) 
                                        AND bd.bd_taxhead_id = 8 
                                        AND bd.isdeleted = 'N') 
                                    ELSE (CASE WHEN
                                            (SELECT  SUM(bdd.tax_amount) 
                                                FROM   cv_bill_detail bdd 
                                                WHERE  bdd.bill_mas_id = sc.bill_id 
                                                AND bdd.tax_id = 8 
                                                AND bdd.status = 'A') = 0 THEN 0 
                                            END) 
                            END), 0)    amt8, 
                        CFC.fc_rrloc_id        FUND, 
                        CFC.fc_fund_center     FCTR, 
                        CFC.fc_business_area   BA, 
                        '99100000000'          FUNCTIONCODE, 
                        '11'                   FUNDCODE, 
                        rr.receipt_date        AS CollDate, 
                        rr.created_at 
                    FROM   cv_receipt_sac_detail sc, 
                           cv_receipt_master rr, 
                           cv_assessment a, 
                           cv_fund_collection cfc, 
                           cv_receipt_tax_detail crtd 
                    WHERE  rr.rct_id = sc.rct_id 
                           AND a.cvp_id = sc.cvp_id 
                           AND cfc.fc_rrloc_id = a.ward_id 
                           AND crtd.rct_det_id = sc.rcpt_det_id 
                           AND crtd.tax_id = 14 
                           AND rr.status = 'A' 
                           AND sc.status = 'A' 
                           AND ( a.status = 'A' 
                                  OR a.status = 'O' ) 
                           AND crtd.status = 'A' 
                    GROUP  BY CFC.fc_rrloc_id, 
                              CFC.fc_fund_center, 
                              rr.created_at, 
                              CFC.fc_business_area, 
                              rr.receipt_date, 
                              crtd.tax_id, 
                              crtd.tax_colln_amt, 
                              a.sac_no, 
                              sc.msr_no, 
                              rr.receipt_no, 
                              rr.receipt_date, 
                              sc.bill_id, 
                              sc.period, 
                              sc.type_of_bill;
```

Below is the Explain plan for it:--

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                    |                       |    257K|      1 |    257K|00:00:27.81 |    2153K|      1 |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | ABM_BILL_DETAIL       |    257K|      1 |    366K|00:00:24.27 |    2153K|      1 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                    |                       |    257K|      1 |   4369K|00:01:44.38 |    1694K|      1 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | CV_PTAX_OUTSTANDING   |    257K|      1 |    380K|00:00:06.82 |     924K|      1 |       |       |          |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN              | INDX_BILLID_PO        |    257K|      1 |    408K|00:00:03.75 |     516K|      0 |       |       |          |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN               | INDX_ABD_BD_BILL_ID   |    380K|      1 |   3730K|00:00:03.91 |     770K|      0 |       |       |          |
|   7 |    SORT AGGREGATE                  |                       |   1679K|      1 |   1679K|00:00:57.53 |    5261K|      0 |       |       |          |
|*  8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | CV_BILL_DETAIL        |   1679K|      1 |   1646K|00:00:52.02 |    5261K|      0 |       |       |          |
|*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN              | INDX_BILL_MAS_ID      |   1679K|     11 |     16M|00:00:18.16 |    3397K|      0 |       |       |          |
|  10 |      SORT AGGREGATE                |                       |    257K|      1 |    257K|00:36:19.20 |    4528K|    414K|       |       |          |
|* 11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | ABM_BILL_DETAIL       |    257K|      1 |    366K|00:36:14.84 |    4528K|    414K|       |       |          |
|  12 |        NESTED LOOPS                |                       |    257K|      1 |   4369K|05:15:33.92 |    4069K|    292K|       |       |          |
|* 13 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CV_PTAX_OUTSTANDING   |    257K|      1 |    380K|00:14:31.47 |    3299K|    196K|       |       |          |
|* 14 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN          | INDX_BILLID_PO        |    257K|      1 |    408K|00:04:58.24 |    2140K|  86191 |       |       |          |
|* 15 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN           | INDX_ABD_BD_BILL_ID   |    380K|      1 |   3730K|00:10:32.73 |     770K|  95900 |       |       |          |
|  16 |        SORT AGGREGATE              |                       |   1679K|      1 |   1679K|00:32:25.01 |    5262K|    571K|       |       |          |
|* 17 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CV_BILL_DETAIL        |   1679K|      1 |   1646K|00:32:18.54 |    5262K|    571K|       |       |          |
|* 18 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN          | INDX_BILL_MAS_ID      |   1679K|     11 |     16M|00:08:35.52 |    3398K|    135K|       |       |          |
|  19 |  HASH GROUP BY                     |                       |      1 |   1607K|    680K|00:00:37.33 |      17M|   1251K|   106M|  7852K|  127M (0)|
|  20 |   VIEW                             |                       |      1 |   1607K|   1941K|00:00:30.86 |      17M|   1251K|       |       |          |
|  21 |    HASH GROUP BY                   |                       |      1 |   1607K|   1941K|00:00:28.92 |      17M|   1251K|   283M|    15M|  283M (0)|
|  22 |     VIEW                           |                       |      1 |   1607K|   1941K|00:00:22.40 |      17M|   1251K|       |       |          |
|  23 |      HASH GROUP BY                 |                       |      1 |   1607K|   1941K|00:00:16.57 |      17M|   1251K|   295M|    15M|  301M (0)|
|* 24 |       HASH JOIN                    |                       |      1 |   1607K|   1941K|00:01:10.72 |     314K|    266K|  1011K|  1011K| 1231K (0)|
|  25 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL           | CV_FUND_COLLECTION    |      1 |     30 |     32 |00:00:00.02 |       3 |      2 |       |       |          |
|* 26 |        HASH JOIN                   |                       |      1 |   1607K|   1941K|00:01:06.82 |     314K|    266K|    39M|  4846K|   53M (0)|
|* 27 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL          | CV_RECEIPT_MASTER     |      1 |    657K|    669K|00:00:00.01 |    9176 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 28 |         HASH JOIN                  |                       |      1 |   1861K|   1941K|00:01:05.64 |     305K|    266K|    16M|  2506K|   24M (0)|
|* 29 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL         | CV_ASSESSMENT         |      1 |    310K|    309K|00:00:00.31 |    6027 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 30 |          HASH JOIN                 |                       |      1 |   1861K|   1941K|00:00:59.14 |     299K|    266K|    67M|  6159K|  103M (0)|
|* 31 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CV_RECEIPT_TAX_DETAIL |      1 |   1859K|   1942K|00:00:29.15 |     268K|    266K|       |       |          |
|* 32 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CV_RECEIPT_SAC_DETAIL |      1 |   1822K|   1951K|00:00:07.81 |   30755 |     28 |       |       |          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(("BD"."BD_TAXHEAD_ID"=7 AND "BD"."ISDELETED"='N'))
   4 - filter((SUBSTR("B"."BILL_CODE",1,6)=SUBSTR("B"."BILL_CODE",1,6) AND "B"."STATUS"='A'))
   5 - access("B"."BILL_ID"=:B1)
   6 - access("B"."BILL_ID"="BD"."BD_BILL_ID")
       filter("BD"."BD_BILL_ID"=:B1)
   8 - filter(("BDD"."TAX_ID"=7 AND "BDD"."STATUS"='A'))
   9 - access("BDD"."BILL_MAS_ID"=:B1)
  11 - filter(("BD"."BD_TAXHEAD_ID"=8 AND "BD"."ISDELETED"='N'))
  13 - filter((SUBSTR("B"."BILL_CODE",1,6)=SUBSTR("B"."BILL_CODE",1,6) AND "B"."STATUS"='A'))
  14 - access("B"."BILL_ID"=:B1)
  15 - access("B"."BILL_ID"="BD"."BD_BILL_ID")
       filter("BD"."BD_BILL_ID"=:B1)
  17 - filter(("BDD"."TAX_ID"=8 AND "BDD"."STATUS"='A'))
  18 - access("BDD"."BILL_MAS_ID"=:B1)
  24 - access("CFC"."FC_RRLOC_ID"="A"."WARD_ID")
  26 - access("RR"."RCT_ID"="SC"."RCT_ID")
  27 - filter("RR"."STATUS"='A')
  28 - access("SC"."CVP_ID"=TO_NUMBER("A"."CVP_ID"))
  29 - filter(("A"."STATUS"='A' OR "A"."STATUS"='O'))
  30 - access("CRTD"."RCT_DET_ID"="SC"."RCPT_DET_ID")
  31 - filter(("CRTD"."TAX_ID"=14 AND "CRTD"."STATUS"='A'))
  32 - filter("SC"."STATUS"='A')
```

Comment: Need help on avoid such redundancy in the sql code

**select dname from dept where deptno=xx**

Below is the example for such sql:-
 select 
 column1,
 column2,
 (select dname from dept where deptno=10) dept10,
 (select dname from dept where deptno=20) dept20
 from dual
 where column1=xyz;

Comment: If you have code that is taking too long to run, post the explain plan. It is very difficult in this instance to see why this code ought to take more than a fraction of a second to execute.

Comment: Hi, this was just the example for the huge sql code written by the developer. Want to understand how the repeated sql code can be avoided  to achieve the same kind of output

Comment: The actual sql query has amt7 and amt8 columns having code redundancy

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM dual
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM dept
  PIVOT(
    max(dname) FOR (deptno) IN (10 as Dept10, 20 as dept20 )
))
/* WHERE column1 = 2 */
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76c878/1

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to give a better query to a sample that is just using dual, but basically instead of doing a query in your result set you should make use of joins.  That will allow the db to select the lowest cost method of joining the tables.  Below is an attempt at an example with what you provided but really doesn't make much sense because dual is being used.  Your query above basically just runs 3 independent queries together, normally you would have them joined together by some related column (XXX).  If not then why even run them as 1 query, run them separately.

```
select column1, column2, d10.dname dept10, d20.dname dept20
from dual left outer join dept d10 on dual.XXX = d10.XXX and d10.deptno = 10
left outer join dept d20 on dual.XXX = d20.XXX and d20.deptno = 20
where column1 = xyz;
```

Running explain plans on your queries really helps you see what the database is actually doing with your query.  When you see full range scans on a large table and the query is slow then that could be a signal that you need an index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the actual sql with the Explain plan for the same.

Answer (score 0):

query logic is not easy to understand and there is no common way to avoid redundancy. Also there is no way to test result and performance.
 Here is an example how query could be changed:

```
WITH 
sc as 
(select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ bill_id, type_of_bill, Substr(period, 1, 4) period, msr_no, rct_id, cvp_id
FROM cv_receipt_sac_detail
WHERE status= 'A'
GROUP BY bill_id, type_of_bill, Substr(period, 1, 4), msr_no, rct_id, cvp_id
)
qamt1 as 
(SELECT  /*+ MATERIALIZE */ a.bill_id, 
        SUM( decode(bd.bd_taxhead_id, 8, Nvl(bd.bd_r_tax_amt, 0) + Nvl( bd.bd_nr_tax_amt, 0)),0) as q1_amt8,
        SUM( decode(bd.bd_taxhead_id, 7, Nvl(bd.bd_r_tax_amt, 0) + Nvl( bd.bd_nr_tax_amt, 0)),0) as q1_amt7
FROM  abm_bill_detail bd, 
         cv_ptax_outstanding b,
         sc a
WHERE bd.bd_bill_id = cs.bill_id 
  AND  b.bill_id = bd.bd_bill_id 
  AND b.status = 'A' 
  AND Substr(b.bill_code, 1, 6) = Substr(b.bill_code, 1, 6) 
  AND bd.bd_taxhead_id IN (8,7)
  AND bd.isdeleted = 'N'
),
qamt2 as 
(SELECT  /*+ MATERIALIZE */ a.bill_id, 
        SUM( decode(bd.bd_taxhead_id, 8, SUM(bdd.tax_amount), 0)) q2_amt8, 
        SUM( decode(bd.bd_taxhead_id, 7, SUM(bdd.tax_amount), 0)) q2_amt7, 
 FROM  cv_bill_detail bdd,
         sc a
WHERE  bdd.bill_mas_id = a.bill_id 
 ANDbd.bd_taxhead_id IN (8,7)
 AND bdd.status = 'A'
)
SELECT  /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ rr.receipt_no, 
                       sc.bill_id             bill_id, 
                       2                      AS sNo, 
                       50                     AS pk, 
                       rr.receipt_date, 
                       a.sac_no, 
                       sc.msr_no, 
                       Decode(crtd.tax_id, '14', SUM(crtd.tax_colln_amt),0) gpen, 
                        (CASE   WHEN sc.type_of_bill = 'M' AND CRTD.tax_id = 14 AND SUM(CRTD.tax_colln_amt) > 0 THEN '350300402' 
                                WHEN sc.type_of_bill = 'R' AND CRTD.tax_id = 14 AND SUM(CRTD.tax_colln_amt) > 0 THEN '350300304' 
                                ELSE '350300104' 
                        END)                GL_Account_code, 
                        Nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN sc.period <= '2009' THEN  q1_amt7
                                              ELSE (CASE WHEN q2_amt7 = 0 THEN 1  END ) 
                                     END), 0)  amt7, 
                        Nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN sc.period <= '2009' THEN  q1_amt8
                                              ELSE (CASE WHEN q2_amt8 = 0 THEN 0  END ) 
                                     END), 0)  amt8,                                          
                    CFC.fc_rrloc_id        FUND, 
                    CFC.fc_fund_center     FCTR, 
                    CFC.fc_business_area   BA, 
                    '99100000000'          FUNCTIONCODE, 
                    '11'                   FUNDCODE, 
                    rr.receipt_date        AS CollDate, 
                    rr.created_at 
           FROM sc,
                    qamt1,
                    qamt2,
                    cv_receipt_master rr, 
                    cv_assessment a, 
                    cv_fund_collection cfc, 
                    cv_receipt_tax_detail crtd 
           WHERE  rr.rct_id = sc.rct_id 
                       AND sc.bill_id = qamt1.bill_id(+) 
                       AND sc.bill_id = qamt2.bill_id(+) 
                       AND a.cvp_id = sc.cvp_id 
                       AND cfc.fc_rrloc_id = a.ward_id 
                       AND crtd.rct_det_id = sc.rcpt_det_id 
                       AND crtd.tax_id = 14 
                       AND rr.status = 'A' 
                       AND a.status IN ( 'A', 'O' ) 
                       AND crtd.status = 'A' 
                GROUP  BY CFC.fc_rrloc_id, 
                          CFC.fc_fund_center, 
                          rr.created_at, 
                          CFC.fc_business_area, 
                          rr.receipt_date, 
                          crtd.tax_id, 
                          crtd.tax_colln_amt, 
                          a.sac_no, 
                          sc.msr_no, 
                          rr.receipt_no, 
                          rr.receipt_date, 
                          sc.bill_id, 
                          sc.period, 
                          sc.type_of_bill;
```